# FirebaseUI doesn't show the new image set for UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdwebimage

I am using FirebaseUI and SDWebImage to set my user's profile pic. It works really good. My problem is when I change the image it gets updated on Firebase Storage and Firebase Database, but it doesn't get updated on app. It still shows the old one there when I restart the app. Here is my code also the  [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files) from Firebase website:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePic: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let userPicRef = firebaseStorageRef.child("users/\(user.uid)")

    let proPIC: UIImageView = self.ProfilePic

    let placeholderImage = UIImage(named: "\(user.uid).jpg")

    proPIC.sd_setImage(with: userPicRef, placeholderImage: placeholderImage)





}
```

Comment: use sd_setImage method with options:SDWebImageRefreshCached

Comment: proPIC.sd_setImage(with: userPicRef, placeholderImage: placeholderImage, options:SDWebImageRefreshCached) something like this in swift

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan I guess `SDWebImageOptions` doesn't work with FirebaseUI, but thanks for help though. I kinda know what to do know.